# Is it possible to run ipython magic commands with root access?

Tags: ipython, root, permission-denied, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to give ipython root access to run its magic commands? Specifically, I am trying to %cd into a mounted directory and am getting a `Permission Denied` error. I'm attempting this from ipython notebook (which I opened with root access), but the same thing happens if I open ipython in a terminal.

I need to do this so that I can get a list of directories to pull data files from. I can use %ls to list them from outside the mounted directory, but I don't think there's a way to save the output from that into variable. Other directory-listing functions (such as glob) don't seem to be able look inside the directory either.

Comment: Did you try simply starting ipython as root? `sudo ipython`

Comment: @yuvi - Yeah, I did. For both ipython and ipython notebook. It doesn't solve the problem in either setting.

Comment: 1) running as root should work. Cd does almost nothing  more than `os.chdir` can you try this one. 2) `files = !ls *.txt` does what you expect.

Comment: @Matt - Those are good ideas. Unfortunately, I can't test them under the original conditions I just found a solution that I don't believe took me this long to think of: I changed the folder permissions with chmod. This made all of the previously discussed methods of accesses the mounted directory work from ipython. However, none of them work from ipython notebook. os.chdir and !ls *.txt both give me Permission denied errors.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is kernel are runned as another user. What does `!whoami` says ?

Comment: !whoami responds with "root". I'm at a loss. As a work around I'm just using a normal python script and saving the output, but its' kind of clunky.

Comment: I just had a need to do some operation from within ipython as root. I tried 'sudo ipython' (which you said didn't work for you) and it worked like a charm.